# Recursively Delete Directory that has space in name

Tags: windows, filenames, batch-processing

I am trying to delete all directories with name `SoftView Cache` recursively in a certain location with the following Batch file:

```
set filename="SoftView Cache"
FOR /d /r "E:\Users\info\OneDrive - Les Entreprises Renouveau\Shared\Image\Plans" %%d IN (%filename%) DO rd /s /q "%%d"
pause
```

This simply returns "The system cannot find the file specified." I am able to see in the command line window that opens, it is searching for `\"SoftView Cache"` instead of `\SoftView Cache` as it should be. I understand that it is the space in the directory name that is causing the trouble. How do I correct the code to find and remove the directories named `SoftView Cache`?

Comment: Filter all found similar folders: **FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %%d in ('DIR /S /B /AD "E:\blablabla\\*%filename%" ^|FIND/i"\%filename%"') DO RD /S /Q "%%d"**

Comment: Your first error was variable set with space-limited string. Should be: **set "filename=SoftView Cache"**

Comment: Command "FOR /D" doesn't return folder names recursively.

Comment: @Daemon-5 It does not seem to make any difference how the variable declaration is double-quoted. It still looks for "SoftView Cache" with literal double quotes.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Your first comment seems to have solved the problem. Could you add it as  an answer so that I could upvote it?

Comment: There is the difference how the variable declaration is double-quoted. Your way includes quotes into variable: **"SoftView Cache"**. Adding variable to path requires removing quotes like this **%filename:"=%**. So I use the way avoiding quotes in variable: **SoftView Cache**. Anyway I was wrong about your error. It is not the error, just another variable usage way.

Answer (score 1):

Use command **DIR** to get folder list by pattern.

Used options:

```
/S - recursively;
/AD - only folders;
/B - full path output.
```

Use command **FIND** to avoid folders which contain leading spaces. Option **/I** ignores case.

Use command **FOR /F** to parse output and send folder's path to command **RD** as parameter

Batch-file code:

```
SET "filename=SoftView Cache"
FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %%d in ('DIR /S /B /AD "E:\blablabla\*%filename%" ^|FIND/i"\%filename%"') DO RD /S /Q "%%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Daemon-5 handled the syntax for the old batch command.

If interested in the PS equivalent, I believe this should do it...  Best regards ~

`Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Users\info\OneDrive - Les Entreprises Renouveau\Shared\Image\Plans" -Include "SoftView Cache" -Directory -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`

Comment: Thank you. I will try this in PS when I get a chance. For some reason I started learning CMD and never got into PS, but I imagine that it's worth the effort?